# How to set a polyline length as per a given Image

Tags: distance, line

I have an image of a map representing the road networks. I have converted these road networks into a shapefile with only polylines. I want to set a distance to this road network. For e.g I know from the image that the distance between A and B is 10 Km. However, I want to set the same distance to the polyline also. Because. If i draw a buffer of 2km for this road network, it goes beyond the size of the image. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I think you did not georeference the raster image correctly before generating shapefiles..

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do.

You can georeference the image using another source that is projected correctly. Something in meteres would be a good choice. Then you could re-extract the road network from the image, and you are good to go.

Or, you can try taking your current (vector) road network and use the spatial adjustment extention in ArcMap to "georeference" the lines.

Good Luck